# Is my understanding of the p-value correct?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, degrees-of-freedom

Say we get some value $t$ from test statistic $T$ for a sample $X$ of size $n$. The $p$-value is the probability that under the null hypothesis $H_0$, we observe a value $v$ of $T$ that is *at least* as extreme as $t$. The value $v$ is outputted for some variation of the $n - 1$ degrees of freedom.

Is this above reasoning correct? I'm a bit confused as to how $v$ is calculated since we already have a known sample $X$ with size $n$ and a known value $t$. Is this calculated after assuming that we now have a different set of $n$ samples?

Comment: The observed sample $x$ is a realisation of $X$, leading to a realisation of $T$, $t$. The $p$-value produces the tail probability $\mathbb P_0(T>t)$ to express how unlikely this very realisation is under the null.

Comment: What do you mean by observed sample $x$ as a realisation of $X$? Is it one item within $X$ or some sample variation of size $n$?

Comment: Please check that video from StatQuest: \
[How to calculate p-values](https://youtu.be/JQc3yx0-Q9E). \
It is wonderful explanation of p-values.